# How to display an array of arrays in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to display an array within another array and I am not sure how.

Here is my code:

```
interface QuestionHeader {
  id: number;
  questionName: string;
  question: Question;
}

interface Question {
  id: number;
  questionContent: string;
  isSelected: false;
}

export default function Questions()  {
  
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionHeader[]>([]);
  useEffect(() =>  {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    fetch(`URL`, requestOptions)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => {
      setQuestions(e)
    });
  },[])
  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <div>
            <ul>
              {questions.map(item=>{
                return (<li>{item.questionName}{item.question.map(q=> )}</li>
                );
                
              })}
            </ul>
...
```

When I try to do `item.map` or `item.question.map`, I get an error that map does not exist in type `Question`.

Comment: As you define the key question on QuestionHeader it is not an array so you cannot iterate over it. If you can provide an response example I could give you extra help.

Comment: response:[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "questionID": 1,
        "questionName": "NPS",
        "question": []
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "questionID": 2,
        "questionName": "Customer Satisfaction",
        "question": [
            {
                "questionID": 2,
                "questionContent": "brand satisfaction"
            }
        ]
    }
]

Comment: you have to declare var index inside the map function (item, index) to fetch array and iterate array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing the QuestionHeader interface to:

```js
interface QuestionHeader {
  id: number;
  questionName: string;
  question: Question[];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
let list_data = [ { "id": 1, "questionID": 1, "questionName": "NPS", 
   "question": [] }, { "id": 2, "questionID": 2, "questionName": "Customer 
    Satisfaction", "question": [ { "questionID": 2, "questionContent": "brand 
    satisfaction" } ] } ] ;

renderListData() {
  return list_data.map((item,i) => <div>
    <label>{item['questionName']}</label>
   <div>{this.renderQuestions(item['question'])}</div>
  </div>)
  }

 renderQuestions(list_que) {
     if(list_que.length > 0) {
       return list_que.map((item,i) => <div>
      <label>{item['questionContent']}</label>
    </div>)
    }
  }
```